# Methodes for Logging in Powershell

Tags: powershell, logging

I wanted to write my own Logging for my scripts.
But there is this smart sentences out there "Do not invent the wheel again"

So I was searching throug the web and found some solutions.
But they seem either to simple (like `Write-Host` into a csv) or to complicated for me to work with it. (Complex with error levels etc).

All I need for myself and my skill level is something like

Create File --> C:\test\log.txt

Write-Log "Removing file `$item` was successfull"

```
New-Item -Path "C:\test\" -Name "ServiceStopped.txt" -ItemType file
Function Write-Log
{
   Param ([string]$logstring)
   $timestamp = Get-Date -Format "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
   $log = "[$timestamp]: $logstring"
   $log >> "ServiceStopped.txt"
}
```

I would like to have an output like

[26.04.2019 12:40]: This has been done

[26.04.2019 12:40]: That has been done

[26.04.2019 12:40]: Working on $a

[26.04.2019 12:40]: Failed while working $b

**EDIT:**

After the friendly tipps in comments I got myself this

```
$Logpath = "C:\test\"
$logname = "ServiceStopped.txt"
New-Item -Path $Logpath -Name $logname -ItemType file
Function Write-Log
{
   Param ([string]$logstring)
   $timestamp = Get-Date -Format "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
   $log = "[$timestamp]: $logstring"
   Add-Content -Value $log -Path "$Logpath\$logname"
}
```

Seems to get the output like I wanted it

Looking further to mentiond `$Error[0]`

Comment: other than the `>>` redirection instead of a proper `Add-Content`, i see no problem with your code. [*grin*] so ... what is your question?

Comment: It seems like you need to add a parameter for your log file location or remove that from your function completely and pipe an output of `Write-Log` to a file.

Comment: Is there a way to make it better without complexing it to much -> this was my first attempt

Comment: A simplistic approach could be to check `$?` after your `New-Item` command. If it is True ($true), then you know it was successful. If it is false ($false), then you know it failed. You can write for each condition within the if statements. You could look at exception in `$error[0]` after a failure and tailor your `$logstring` based on that. [About_Try_Catch_Finally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally?view=powershell-6) is also useful.

Comment: If you don't want to re-invent the wheel ... there are some logging "frameworks" out there with some advantages ... one of it might suit your requirements ... [Powershellgallery - Logging](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages?q=logging)